# Fixed Window Placement - How can I switch to a specific workspace upon opening an application?

Tags: compiz, workspaces

I've configured **Terminal** to always open on workspace 3 using Compiz - this is working fine. What I want is for **Terminal** to open on workspace 3 and for workspace 3 to become my active workspace.

For example:

I'm on workspace 1, doing something. I suddenly want to open **Terminal** and run some commands, Ctrl+Alt+T gets me a new Terminal window in workspace 3, but I'm still in workspace 1 and I can't see it. Now, in addition to opening the Terminal window, I need to Alt+Tab to get to it.

Is there a way that I can make applications that have been set to open in a specific workspace also take me to that workspace if I'm not there already - AND have that application as the 'current' active application (as if I've just Alt+Tab'd to it)?